# Python white space symbol removing \s

Tags: python, regex, trim

For example I have this address \sgoogle.com and I use

```
line.strip(' \s') # it displays google.com as it must be
```

But when I try it on \sgoogle\s.com it works bad(the result is googles.com).Does anyone know whats wrong and how to fix ?

Comment: `strip` only removes leading/trailing chars

Comment: Use some regex lib function like `Regex.Replace(pattern,input)`. We use this kind of function in C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thought I might include an alternative (Python 2 only):

```
>>> s = '\sgoogle\s.com'
>>> s.translate(None, '\s')
'google.com'
```

In Python 3 it would be:

```
>>> s.translate(s.maketrans('', '', '\s'))
'google.com'
```

Answer (score 4):

`strip()` only removes these characters at the start and the end of the string, not in the middle of the string. If you want to remove it anywhere in a string, use [replace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace):

```
'\sgoogle\s.com'.replace('\s', '');
```